# Does pollution render activities haram?

Tags: halal-haram, najis

Nowadays, many tasks inevitably result in some degree of pollution.  Transportation, be it driving cars, having non-local food shipped internationally, or even flying to Mecca to perform Hajj, is a major cause of environmental damage across the globe.  Even the Internet, which I am using right now, requires not only my own computer but also the running of any number of servers between me and my destination, all of which take their environmental toll.

Are such activities haram due to this?  Also if they are haram, then could planting trees be a solution?

Comment: Some comments:

Its more like a question of the type: To save some people I have to kill an innocent people, so is killing innocent people halal? Its more about the act than something other. See, that is a black and white question. ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is going to Mecca by aircraft haram?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9871/is-going-to-mecca-by-aircraft-haram)

Answer (score -1):

Although I am not a mufti (so you should still get this checked with a scholar) I would suggest that it appears not to be haraam on the basis that no Islamic scholar I've known has objected to riding a car, and I am guessing the same applies to most people.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism or seeking clarifications in a post.  They are not intended for extended discussion and/or debate; please use the [chat] for that instead.

Answer (score -1):

In the Name of Allah, Most Gracious, Most Merciful.

All praise and thanks are due to Allah, and peace and blessings be upon His Messenger.

Your question is very interesting. I hope to ensure a convincing answer.

No doubt, Islam considers pollution as harmful to society. It’s not just a question relating to property that can be settled by compensating the injured party (victim of pollution). Rather, Islam obliges the whole society to avoid polluting the environment. This is the theme of the Qur’anic verse:

> “*Do no mischief on the earth, after it hath been set in order, but
> call on Him with fear and longing (in your hearts): for the Mercy of
> Allah is (always) near to those who do good.*” **(Al-`Araf: 56)**

Shedding more light on this issue, we’d like to cite for you the fatwa issued by Dr. `Abdul Fattah Idris, professor of comparative jurisprudence, Al-Azhar University. It goes as follows:

> “Whoever causes pollution of any kind in Islam, he is sinful and is
> committing a forbidden act. This is due to the fact that pollution
> affects both Muslims and non-Muslims and all living creatures as well.
> In this regard, Prophet Muhammad, peace and blessings be upon him,
> said, “There should be neither harm, nor reciprocating injury.” Also,
> Prophet Muhammad, peace and blessings be upon him, warned against
> urinating or defecating in people’s pathways, in water and in the
> shade of trees as all these things are of great benefit to people.”

Also, the Qur’an says that Allah is the Creator of the world. Human beings are on the world as trustees or ‘vicegerents’ - they are told to look after the world for Allah and for the future:

> *"The Earth is green and beautiful, and Allah has appointed you his stewards over it. The whole earth has been created a place of worship, pure and clean. Whoever plants a tree and diligently looks after it until it matures and bears fruit is rewarded. If a Muslim plants a tree or sows a field and humans and beasts and birds eat from it, all of it is love on his part."*
>
> Hadith

In the Qur’an, Muslims are instructed to look after the environment and not to damage it:

> *Devote thyself single-mindedly to the Faith, and thus follow the nature designed by Allah, the nature according to which He has
> fashioned mankind. There is no altering the creation of Allah.*
>
> **Surah 30:30**

Muslims have to look after the earth because it is all Allah’s creation and it is part of a human’s duty to Allah:

> *Allah is He Who raised up the heavens without any pillars that you can see. Then He settled Himself on the Throne, and constrained the
> sun and the moon to serve you; each planet pursues its course during
> an appointed term. He regulates it all and expounds the Signs, that
> you may have firm belief in the meeting with your Lord. He it is Who
> spread out the earth and made therein firmly fixed mountains and
> rivers, and of fruits of every kind He has made pairs. He causes the
> night to cover the day. In all this, verily, are signs doer a people
> who reflect.*
>
> **Surah 13:3-4**

Because of this passage, people see themselves as being responsible for the world which Allah created and they have to make their own decisions about how to do this.

We know proved that pollution and every activity that cause it is haram. So yes, cars are haram, air planes are haram, the internet is haram... And planting trees is very recommended but they only absorb carbon dioxide (so they limit only air pollution) and therefore cannot completely clean the other pollutants.

Allah knows the best.

Comment: Then you should also consider that paving roads and building houses would be haram as you changed the nature created by Allah. The origin of anything is halal unless you have a clear source and what about the pollution which comes from fire for cocking, forging etc. why this is halal? And we have a Verse which show as that we can use anything on earth http://quran.com/31/20 but as muslims we have to use it with care and in a responsible way!

Answer (score -1):

Masjd has responded correctly, however most muslims are human beings after all and thus subjected to the pressure of peripheral influence regardless of the strength in their faith.

People need their cars, they eat their meat, they use detergents and even much of the cloth and shoes we wear pollute our surroundings.